# linker command failed with exit code 1 (error; cannot seem to fix it)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, error-handling

I keep on getting this error in my code:

```
Ld /Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Products/Debug/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2 normal x86_64
cd "/Users/mregdosz/Documents/Absolute C++/Absolute C++/Chapter 3 Absolute C++/Chapter 3 Absolute C++/Chapter 3 project 10/Chapter 3 Project 10 Take 2"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Products/Debug -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/system -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/system/introspection -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/dtrace -F/Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Intermediates/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2.build/Debug/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework AddressBook -framework AGL -framework AppKit -framework AppKitScripting -framework AppleScriptKit -framework AppleScriptObjC -framework AppleShareClientCore -framework ApplicationServices -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework AudioVideoBridging -framework Automator -framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o -framework CalendarStore -framework Carbon -framework CFNetwork -framework Cocoa -framework Collaboration -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreAudioKit -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMediaIO -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreServices -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreWLAN /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o -framework DirectoryService -framework DiscRecording -framework DiscRecordingUI -framework DiskArbitration -framework DrawSprocket -framework DVComponentGlue -framework DVDPlayback /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.10.5.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o -framework EventKit -framework ExceptionHandling -framework ForceFeedback -framework Foundation -framework FWAUserLib -framework GameController -framework GameKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o -framework GLKit -framework GLUT -framework GSS -framework ICADevices -framework ImageCaptureCore -framework ImageIO -framework IMServicePlugIn -framework InputMethodKit -framework InstallerPlugins -framework InstantMessage -framework IOBluetooth -framework IOBluetoothUI -framework IOKit -framework IOSurface -framework JavaFrameEmbedding -framework JavaScriptCore -framework JavaVM -framework Kerberos -framework Kernel -framework LatentSemanticMapping /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/lazydylib1.o -framework LDAP -lACSClient -lalias.A -lalias -lapr-1.0.4.5 -lapr-1.0 -lapr-1 -laprutil-1.0.3.12 -laprutil-1.0 -laprutil-1 -larchive.2 -larchive -lauditd.0 -lauditd -lauto -lblas -lBSDPClient.A -lBSDPClient -lbsm.0 -lbsm -lbz2.1.0.5 -lbz2.1.0 -lbz2 -lc++.1 -lc++ -lc++abi -lc -lcache -lcblas -lcharset.1.0.0 -lcharset.1 -lcharset -lclapack -lcmph -lcom_err -lcommonCrypto -lcompiler_rt -lcopyfile -lcorecrypto -lCoreStorage -lCRFSuite -lCRFSuite0.12 -lcrypto.0.9.7 -lcrypto.0.9.8 -lcrypto -lcsfde -lcups.2 -lcups -lcupscgi.1 -lcupscgi -lcupsimage.2 -lcupsimage -lcupsmime.1 -lcupsmime -lcupsppdc.1 -lcupsppdc -lcurl.3 -lcurl.4 -lcurl -lcurses -ldbm -ldes425 -lDHCPServer.A -lDHCPServer -lDiagnosticMessagesClient -ldispatch -ldispatch -ldl -ldns_services -ldtrace -ldtrace_dyld -ldyld -lecpg.6.4 -lecpg.6 -lecpg -lecpg_compat.3.4 -lecpg_compat.3 -lecpg_compat -ledit.2 -ledit.3.0 -ledit.3 -ledit -lexpat.1.5.2 -lexpat.1 -lexpat -lexslt.0 -lexslt -lf77lapack -lffi -lform.5.4 -lform -lgcc_s.1 -lgcc_s.10.4 -lgcc_s.10.5 -lgermantok -lgmalloc.B -lgmalloc -lgssapi_krb5 -lheimdal-asn1 -lhunspell-1.2.0.0.0 -lhunspell-1.2.0 -lhunspell-1.2 -liconv.2.4.0 -liconv.2 -liconv -licucore.A -licucore -linfo -liodbc.2.1.18 -liodbc.2 -liodbc -liodbcinst.2.1.18 -liodbcinst.2 -liodbcinst -lipconfig -lipsec.A -lipsec -lk5crypto -lkeymgr -lkrb4 -lkrb5 -lkrb524 -lkrb5support -lkxld -llangid -llapack -llaunch -llber -lldap -lldap_r -llzma.5 -llzma -lm -lmacho -lMatch.1 -lMatch -lmathCommon.A -lmathCommon -lmecab.1.0.0 -lmecab -lmecabra -lmenu.5.4 -lmenu -lmx.A -lmx -lncurses.5.4 -lncurses.5 -lncurses -lnetsnmp.15.1.2 -lnetsnmp.15 -lnetsnmp.25 -lnetsnmp.5.2.1 -lnetsnmp.5 -lnetsnmp -lnetsnmpagent.25 -lnetsnmpagent -lnetsnmphelpers.25 -lnetsnmphelpers -lnetsnmpmibs.25 -lnetsnmpmibs -lnetsnmptrapd.25 -lnetsnmptrapd -lobjc.A -lobjc -lodfde -lodmodule -lOpenScriptingUtil -lpam.1 -lpam.2 -lpam -lpanel.5.4 -lpanel -lpcap.A -lpcap -lpcre.0 -lpcre -lpcreposix.0 -lpcreposix -lpgtypes.3.3 -lpgtypes.3 -lpgtypes -lpoll -lpq.5.5 -lpq.5 -lpq -lproc -lpthread -lquarantine -lquit -lreadline -lremovefile -lresolv.9 -lresolv -lrpcsvc -lruby.2.0.0 -lruby.2.0 -lruby -lsandbox.1 -lsandbox -lsasl2.2.0.1 -lsasl2.2.0.15 -lsasl2.2.0.21 -lsasl2.2.0.22 -lsasl2.2 -lsasl2 -lScreenReader -lspindump -lsqlite3.0 -lsqlite3 -lssl.0.9.7 -lssl.0.9.8 -lssl -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lstdc++.6 -lstdc++ -lsysmon -lSystem.B -lSystem.B_debug -lSystem -lsystem_asl -lsystem_blocks -lsystem_c -lsystem_configuration -lSystem_debug -lsystem_dnssd -lsystem_info -lsystem_kernel -lsystem_m -lsystem_malloc -lsystem_network -lsystem_notify -lsystem_platform -lsystem_pthread -lsystem_sandbox -lsystem_stats -ltcl -ltcl8.5 -ltermcap -ltidy.A -ltidy -ltk -ltk8.5 -lunc -lUniversalAccess -lunwind -lutil -lutil1.0 -lxar.1 -lxar -lxcselect -lxml2.2 -lxml2 -lxpc -lXplugin.1 -lXplugin -lxsanmgrcommon -lxslt.1 -lxslt -lz.1.1.3 -lz.1.2.5 -lz.1 -lz -framework MapKit -framework MediaAccessibility -framework MediaLibrary -framework MediaToolbox -framework NetFS -framework OpenAL -framework OpenCL -framework OpenDirectory -framework OpenGL -framework OSAKit -framework PCSC -framework PreferencePanes -framework PubSub -framework QTKit -framework Quartz -framework QuartzCore -framework QuickLook -framework QuickTime -framework Ruby -framework RubyCocoa -framework SceneKit -framework ScreenSaver -framework Scripting -framework ScriptingBridge -framework Security -framework SecurityFoundation -framework SecurityInterface -framework ServiceManagement -framework Social -framework SpriteKit -framework StoreKit -framework SyncServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Tcl -framework Tk -framework TWAIN -framework VideoDecodeAcceleration -framework VideoToolbox -framework WebKit -framework DTPerformanceSession -framework InterfaceBuilderKit -framework SenTestingKit -framework XCTest -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Intermediates/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2.build/Debug/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mregdosz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chapter_3_Absolute_C++-fudhoiytotorpfhkhmdsghdoaicn/Build/Products/Debug/Chapter\ 3\ Project\ 10\ Take\ 2
```

ld: framework not found Kernel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am at a lose. I have been looking all day yesterday for a solution and I cannot seem to find one. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It says Framework not found..which framework is it not finding exactly? 
Are you trying load any 3rd party frameworks and if so have you tried copying them into your project directory? If that hasn't worked then make sure that the Framework's directory is being looked for under the `Framework Search Paths` option under your `Build Settings`

Comment: From what I know I have not. One moment it was working and then I tweaked the program a bit and then I received this error. The first thing I tried was to take out the tweak and see if it would work again but I received the error again after taking the tweak out. I am at a loss.